# Pandas read csv is not separating the columns properly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a txt file that looks like this[txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36qjj.png), but using

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', encoding='utf-8')
```

does not separate correctly columns. How can I solve it?

I was expecting to be correctly separated. I get this:

```
 "",t,I_m [A] 4.002,Tm [Nm],V_bus [V] 5.005,n [rpm] 0.010,T_inv [ºC] 7.034,T_acu [%] 4.019,f_m [Hz] 5.001,V_m [V] 5.002,P_m [kW] 5.003,n_ref [rpm] 3.001,I_m_par [A] 4.002,P_m_par [W] 5.003,Unnamed: 13
0,12:00:52,0.0,0.0,560.0,0.0,51.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN
1,12:00:52,0.0,0.0,560.0,0.0,51.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN
2,12:00:52,0.0,0.0,560.0,0.0,51.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN
3,12:00:52,0.0,0.0,561.0,0.0,51.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN
4,12:00:52,0.0,0.0,561.0,0.0,51.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,NaN,NaN
```

Ignore the index

Comment: Please post your text file as text, not an image of text.

Comment: Is it wrong somehow? Since we don't see the tabs, we can't know where this this is supposed to divide. Perhaps you could make an example with fewer columns and only 2 rows that has the same problem. Based on the NaN padding, I suspect it is creating too many columns. Which is the first column that goes bad? That could be where you make a smaller example. Then post that exact sample in a code block for us to test.

Comment: It's impossible to tell what's happening because we have no idea what the separators are in your input file. If you're not getting the column names as you would have hoped then it's likely that they're not separated by tab

Answer (score 0):

Try checking for spaces

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\s+', encoding='utf-8', skipinitialspace=True)
```

`skipinitialspace` is for checking if there is spaces before text and as in image it is present. Using `'\s+'` ensures to check for all combination of space and treating that as a delimeter.

Also as far as I can see the problem I see that there is a combination of both tab `'\t'` and spaces `'\s+'`.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the file in your screenshot, the output looks like the file is actually comma-separated and not tab-separated. Try removing the `sep='\t'` parameter:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, encoding='utf-8')
```